# Do I need to sell my shares during a merger proactively

Tags: stocks, corporate-acquisition

I hold shares in the publicly traded company I work for. This company is now being acquired via a cash merger by a second company.

They put out a press release expressing their intent to buy all outstanding shares at a 44% percent premium. Subsequently, the stock price of my shares has gone up by roughly 40% but the merger has not yet been approved by the authorities.

My question: Do I have to proactively sell my shares now / after the merger has been approved? Or is the transaction handled by my broker automatically after the second company bought 90% of the outstanding shares and the remaining shares will no longer be able to be traded. I'm asking because selling would incur a fee at my broker and I'd like to take the offer of the 44% premium instead of selling at market price now.

Comment: What do you think will happen to share price if the merger isn't approved by the authorities?

Comment: it will crash down to the original price or a little lower than that. I'm certain that the merger will go through though since the buyer already purchased around 45% and the target is too small for cartel worries. The buyer already has a track record of more than 100 successful mergers

Comment: If you're  certain that the merger will go through then you have no worries.

Comment: right, that means I should just keep my shares and wait for the broker to cash them out?

Comment: If you believe that the deal is going to go through and the buyer will acquire  all outstanding shares at a 44% percent premium then there's nothing to do.

Comment: I'm confused by "Do I **have to** proactively sell my shares*".  Why do you think it's **mandatory** that you proactively sell your shares?

Comment: @RonJohn This is the first time something like this is happening to my shares and after reading everything on investopedia about mergers, I still was not sure whether I would automatically get the 44% offer if I do not sell. I thought maybe my shares would just be liquidated at a lower price when they stop trading

Comment: Ah, I see.  IIRC, the purchasing company will send you a package in the mail which you must then sign and return saying that you accept their offer to buy at such-and-such a price.

Comment: @RonJohn Really? Wow that must be some effort there must be thousands of small time investors like me.. Anyway, thank you, I'll just wait until I hear something from my broker or the company. It was just important for me to understand that doing nothing now would not mean a loss for me

Comment: Even if the merger is disallowed, say for antitrust reasons, the offer establishes what an acquirer is willing to pay. Expect another deal at a similar or even higher price to follow, e.g., **TRCO**.

Comment: @RonJohn: only if you hold the shares directly (i.e. are registered with the transfer agent or registrar). If you hold the shares in a brokerage account (also called 'street name') as it appears this OP does, the broker will automatically handle the action; see https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/106558/what-happens-to-the-shares-of-company-a-in-a-brokerage-account-when-company . However, merging a public company requires a vote of stockholders, so in _either_ case (direct or street name) you will first receive a 'proxy solicitation' asking you to vote your shares.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to sell now. When the merger closes, your broker will automatically sell the shares for you.

However, you may *want* to sell now, to avoid the risk that the deal falls apart. You mention that the current market price is close but not equal to the acquisition price. Merger arbitrage professionals trade these deals based on the estimated probability of successful closing. But if you are not in the risk arb business, you don't necessarily want to place that bet (by continuing to hold) when the upside from here is small. You can decide if getting the last few percent is worth the small chance that the deal fails, no other buyer steps in, and the stock plunges.